# Reproducing arrows with TikZ

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows

I would like to reproduce this type of arrows with TikZ :

[image]

It's not the " dotted " part which annoys me, but the end of the arrow. I searched for this arrows in the manual, but did not find a way to reproduce this. In fact, I don't even know if this picture has been produced with TikZ or not.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT : following a comment below, here is a zoom on the end of the arrow.

[image]

Comment: It seems a quite elongated `-Triange`. Could you please zoom on the arrow tip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green!30] (0,0) rectangle (3,-2);
\fill[green!70!black] (2,-1) circle [radius=0.05];
\draw[green!70!black, densely dotted, shorten >=2.5, line cap=round, -{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .4, length=3pt]}] (0,0) -- (2,-1); 
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image: Round triangle arrow]

Comment: impressive :) thanks !